# printing multiple different things in single printf statement using C

Tags: c, printf, double

I'm trying to turn three printf statements into one longer statement, in C.
I wish to turn:

```
printf("The current system time is ");
printf("%f", get_current_time());
printf("\n");
```

into a single `printf` statement, where function `get_current_time` returns a `double`, such as `1459231814.421397` or similar.
The closest I have managed to get is

```
printf("The current system time is " , ("%f" (get_current_time())), "\n");
```

which returns only one error, which is:

`error: called object is not a function or function pointer`:

`printf("The current system time is " , ("%f" (get_current_time())), "\n");"`

and it points out the `"` before the `%f`.

the three separated `printf` statements print:

`"The current system time is 1459231876.947026"`

or similar a set amount of times, each time on a new line, which is what I want.

I don't understand why it works when separated, but adding them together into one long statement fails. I'm sure I must be formatting the longer statement incorrectly, just not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.
Any help is hugely appreciated, and sorry if this question is not formatted very well, it's the first question I've asked.

Comment: Wow thanks for all the quick answers everyone :D All answers work perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following :

```
printf ( "The current system time is %f\n", get_current_time() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why nobody mentioned this yet, but:

```
printf("The current system time is %f\n", get_current_time());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("The current system time is %f \n",get_current_time());
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the basic use case for `printf`

```
printf("%s%f\n", "The current system time is ", get_current_time());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
printf("%s%f\n", "The current system time is ", get_current_time());
```

or

```
printf("The current system time is %f\n", get_current_time());
```

Comment: Wow, we produced exactly the same line, though there are some more options format the desired output ;)